# Как сфоткать сайт целиком

Tags: html, html5

Мне надо сделать скрин всего лендинга. Для портфолио. Как или с помощью чего я могу это сделать?

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Попробуй расширение **fireshot**

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не связан с программированием

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome позволяет делать скришоты, вот [ссылка](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots)